# Flight search engine that displays prices including 1 checked bag

Tags: air-travel, luggage, flight-search-engines

I'm looking for a flight search engine that displays flight ticket prices including 1 checked bag. I tried Kiwi and Skyscanner but they sometimes (always?) display flight ticket prices without including the price for 1 checked bag, which I've seen can be up to 250 USD, even when I indicate that I have 1 checked bag in Kiwi's or Skyscanner's search interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kayak lets you specify how many checked bags and how many carry-ons.  But you have to "keep an eye on" the setting because they keep setting it back to zero when you do things on the site.

Comment: Thanks, does kayak use the number of checked bags when displaying the flight ticket prices?

Comment: From my memory, when I change it, the prices are updated.  But my last flight was more than a year ago.

Answer (score 7):

[Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights) can do it:

[image]

[Their help article on the topic](https://support.google.com/travel/answer/9074247?hl=en) gives a little bit more information.

Answer (score 2):

The [PanFlights](https://panflights.com) metasearch engine allows luggage fee inclusion. With it you can select one large carry-on and up to two checked bags.

Note that the fees are not always available.

Disclosure: I'm developing PanFlights.

[image: luggage selector]

[image: Additional information]

[image: luggage fee selector shown in context]